# Clean reinstall on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation

New to CiviCRM. 
WordPress Version: 4.4.2
PHP Version: 5.5.32
MySQL Version: 5.1.73-log

I initially installed CiviCRM 4.6.14 LTS by mistake and rather than do an upgrade, I deactivated it, deleted it, and dropped all the tables from the database (It was installed to its own DB).

I neglected to remove the plugins/files directory or its contents, though.

I then installed 4.7.3 and when I activated it, I had green lights all the way on the installation page, so I just proceeded. However, any attempts to open CiviCRM resulted in errors (something about MySQL MyISAM).

So, I deactivated, deleted and then found that the db files were put in my Wordpress database, not the CiviCRM db. I deleted all those, and reinstalled 4.7.3.

Now, when I activate, I get a SQL Error -- table not found. Obviously, CiviCRM is still trying to use the WP database. I wholly expected to get the Install page again, but that never happened.

What setting is lurking around that uninstalling doesn't delete? How can I get a clean install that runs the installation check and lets me enter the alternate DB info. I tried https://MYSITE/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civicrm-install, but all I get is "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.")

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the error message I get when I try to activate civicrm:
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

```
[code] => -18
[message] => DB Error: no such table
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
```

FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'db561663860.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'db561663860.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'db561663860.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]
)

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in MYSITE/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsBag.php on line 311content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsBag.php on line 311

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling CiviCRM doesn't delete its settings which are stored inside `wp-content/uploads/civicrm` folder. The best option is to delete that folder (it solves this issue in my case).

**WARNING!** Remember about making backups before deleting anything.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be instead of fixing the existing instance please try to install an fresh copy which will be easier

please refer to the following link for installation process
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5

---

If you want to fix the existing Installation then please look for civicrm.settings.php file

you can find the file against .../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

you can see CIVICRM_UF_DSN and CIVICRM_DSN this will say which DB is been linked make your changes also clear cache and try again it should work

thanks - I guess this helps!

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, I did that. Uninstalled, deleted all the files -- through WordPress and then checked manually. I even deleted the plugin/files folder in hope that that would then be "clean". There is no civicrm.settings.php file in my new install.

Comment: Please try to create an new instance of Wordpress and try to install CiviCRM again and do follow the steps in the link given - thanks

Comment: None of that worked until I found and deleted (renamed) the civicrm folder in the wp-content/uploads folder. THEN, it went through the requirements check, let me re-specify the database connection, and recreated the DB tables. However, now I get THIS error: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 39059456) (tried to allocate 1792 bytes) in /MYSITE/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 342. If I click on the CiviCRM admin link, I get this System Status: Error

    MyISAM Database Engine
    Cron Not Running
    Configure Default Mailbox
    Complete Setup
Will try running the DB scripts manually.

Comment: Please check your MySQL memory space - for Out Of Memory Issue And by Default all the table should be InnoDB have you created any new table on your own if so please try to check the property of the table and change it to InnoDB -

Comment: @PaulN Your out of memory issue is related to PHP memory_limit, which CiviCRM needs to be at least 192M